# How to copy objects between sessions in NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, nhibernate

I would like to copy my entities from MySQL database to brand new SQLite database (export).
I have the code below:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> fooList;
using (var sf = CreateMySqlSessionFactory("user", "password"))
using (var source = sf.OpenSession())
using (var sf2 = Class1.CreateSqliteSessionFactory(outputPath))
using (var dest = sf2.OpenSession())
{
     fooList = source.Query<Foo>();
     foreach (var foo in fooList)
     {
         dest.SaveOrUpdate(foo);
     }
     dest.Flush();
}
```

Both session factories are created without problems. Unfortunately SaveOrUpdate throws LazyInitializationException with message:

*Illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions*

I understand that both sessions are open, but I couldn't find any neat solution.
The only ones I could find were about deep-cloning each foo, which too cumbersome (foo has properties of bar objects, which have another properties of boo objects etc.).

How can I perform such a bulk copy using NHibernate?
Please mind that the schema of source and destination databases are NOT the same. I used different mappings to achieve that.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
I'm doing the exact same thing. And I noticed that I have to do a `source.Clear()` before I can do the save operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried detaching foo from the session using:

```
source.Evict(foo)
```

Comment: Still the same error. Probably, I would have to evict foo, foo.bar, foo.bar.boo etc.